# How to set JAVA_HOME when I use the method "Runtime.getRuntime().exec" in Intellij Idea?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, java-8, exec, java-11

I want to use "jdeps" command to analyze some jar files' dependencies. My OS is Windows10. The core code is

```
String command = String.format("jdeps \"%s\"", path.toAbsolutePath().toString());
String format = String.format("cmd.exe /c %s", command);
process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(format);
```

There are 2 JDK version in my computer, JDK11 and JDK8. I want to use JDK11 and I set environment variable JAVA_HOME to JDK11's path. When I use cmd windows to execute the code, it works as I want, but If I run it in Intellij Idea, the JDK is changed to JDK8.

I'm sure that I have set the **Project Settings--Project--Project SDK** to JDK11. **Project language level** is SDK default(11-Local variable syntax for lambda parameters). **Modules--Sources--Language level** is "11-Local variable syntax for lambda parameters". The Java Compiler of Intellij Idea is also set to 11. There is nothing about JDK8 in my Intellij Idea.

But If I run my code in Intellij Idea, the JDK is still changed to JDK8. That makes me crazy. Is it a bug? What can I do to set JDK11?

By the way, I exec the "setx JAVA_HOME" command to set JAVA_HOME to JDK11 in my code, but it does not work.

Comment: Note that if needed you can specify/change specific environment variables in [Run/Debug Configurations in IDE](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/run-debug-configuration-application.html).

Answer (score 0):

None of that uses `JAVA_HOME`.

When you execute `jdeps` like that, unqualified, you'll use the version that is on the `PATH`.

Either change the `PATH`, or qualify the command.

E.g. I don't have Java on the `PATH`, by default, so running `jdeps` unqualified fails, but I can run it if I qualify the command:

```
C:\>jdeps -version
'jdeps' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\>C:\prog\Java64\jdk1.8.0_181\bin\jdeps -version
1.8.0_181

C:\>C:\prog\Java64\jdk-13.0.2\bin\jdeps -version
13.0.2
```

Comment: Unfortunately I have added JDK11's bin foler path to the environment variable **Path** and put the path to the first place. Of cause I can get the right result when I use cmd to run my code. But it is  wrong in Intellij Idea. Is there a **Path** variable in Intellij Idea?

Comment: @S.Lee Why don't you just ask the system what the path is? E.g. `System.getProperties` inside Java, or run `cmd.exe /k echo %PATH%` to see what commands run from Java get?

Comment: Of course, you can get the current value of `PATH` in Java as well, just using `System.getenv("PATH")`. But there is no reason to mess around with it. When you want to run the `jdeps` command of the same Java installation you’re currently running in, use `System.getProperty("java.home")` (which is not the same as JAVA_HOME) and navigate to the right bin directory. Or use the first path element of `System.getProperty("java.library.path")`…

Comment: @Andreas You remind me. I run echo %PATH% in my code. There is not any path of  JDK11 in the result. So I restart my computer and the problem is resolved. I had tried to restart my Intellij Idea, but it dose not work. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Intellij Idea use the PATH in environment variables if I did not set anything.
I run echo %PATH% in my code. The result is different with system environment variables. I had tried to restart my Intellij Idea, but it dose not work. Finally, I restart my computer and it works.